# What is the regex for a group of 6 numbers hyphen separated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am using Ruby on Rails and I "am a newbie" / "don't remember how" to matching regular expressions. I would like to [`validates_format_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_format_of) with regex matching following strings:

```
122-162-281-5-0-221
122-162-281-05-00-221
122-162-281-005-000-221
```

Note: The regex should match a group of *6* numbers (each number is minimum 1 digit and maximum 3 digits) hyphen separated.

What is the regex?

Comment: -1 Why? Because no effort was shown. Now would be a good time to "learn regular expression syntax" / "refresh on syntax you used to know". Once a basic regular expression is shown, then that can be used as a basis for responses. It either works - in which case the  question is "how to improve it?", or it doesn't work - and the question is, "why not?".

Comment: @pst, you are perfectly right. How many things are you able to remember? ...

Comment: One thing I *do* remember is that if I type a series of relevant words - like "ruby regex tutorial" - into a search engine, I am often rewarded with useful resources. ***I forget things all the time*** (and search quite a bit).

Comment: @pst, the goal of stack overflow is to be **the** repository of definitive answers to programming questions. Both of the founders have expressed this *endlessly*, and when they've quibbled over how simple a question to allow the resolution has always been permissive, not restrictive. It may be that there is an answer in search engine results that isn't reflected on stack overflow: that is a page missing from stack overflow! Instead of chastising people who ask questions, either provide an answer or support those who do.

Comment: @eyelidlessness In my first comment *I explained the reason for down-vote*, even including a reason for why *showing effort* is good, besides making me feel less like a free programming service. And no, I do not feel like this question is good on SO, which is why I voted it as Too Localized. There are an infinite number of identical (except for replacing *the task*) regular expression questions that could be asked.

Comment: @eyelidlessness Just think how much more useful this question would be if it *provided a basis* and was something less Too Localized after following the question "how to improve it?": "How can an a repeating expression pattern (e.g. X-X-X-X) be simplified?"

Comment: @pst Have you tried to search for "ruby regex tutorial" or strings like that? How do you find one of the "infinite number of identical regular expression questions that could be asked" like in my case?

Comment: @Backo 1. Yes. Try it - without the quotes of course - in Google and click on the first link. I will spare a link to lmgtfy. 2. "What is the regex for a group of 5 letters spacee separated?"

Comment: Try you - without the quotes, of course - as a proof that fits my case, even if you are still using Google...

Comment: @pst, admittedly I have spent years arguing with people who downvote/flag questions because OMG LMGTFY, so I am biased. I understand the desire for more information about what effort has been tried, and frankly I push my coworkers all the time to provide more information about *what **exactly** they want* when they ask questions. But ultimately I think the goal of stack overflow is a noble one. I *want* there to be a single repository of answers to all programming questions. I am *flabbergasted* when people *here* suggest others seek their answers elsewhere.

Comment: @eyelidlessness Please reread my initial comment. Disagreement with providing the keywords to **learn how to solve this *task*** does not make it a good question. Had it remained at +0 I would have withheld a down-vote, but how can this actually be *getting* votes? Well, it is popular enough I guess ..

Comment: @pst, I don't disagree with providing keywords to learn how to solve this task. I have a problem with ever *ever* **EVER** seeing the letters "lmgtfy" on this site, even (especially) in the passive-aggressive form. In terms of your initial response and my own response to it, I would likewise say reread my initial comment. SO is for *all* programming questions. Your use of "too localized" is not reflective in the least of the spirit of that term. I think it's fair to say that the question could have been better worded and specified; (cont'd)

Comment: I also think the user base of this site makes "could have been better worded" a VERY poor reason to downvote a question. There are MANY reasons things are not worded to my liking here, and I ALWAYS check that expectation and try to intuit reasons why things might not meet that expectation before I reply. We're here to be helpful, first and foremost. The best way to correct others is to be correct ourselves. The downvote of a question is for misuse, not for lack of expertise. The question is *provided* for people who lack expertise. The downvote of an *answer* is for correctness.

Comment: I guess I should have just kept my initial comment short instead, of, you know, explanatory: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @pst, I also appreciate the fact that you provided explanation of your downvote. It doesn't mean I have to agree with your reasoning. I just think that "LMGTFY" or "WHYT" should be regarded as "comment smells".

Comment: @eyelidlessness The introduction of lmgtfy was much later (note the progression of comments). This is the first time I have used it in years (well, likely months), and in this case *I really do mean it*. I do not believe SO should be a "task board".

Comment: @pst, you're right that "LMGTFY" was later... but "WHYT" was essentially the thrust of your initial comment and what I responded to. The addition of "LMGTFY" was just a smell upon a smell. (Edit: and the one usually reflects the sentiment of the other.)

Comment: @eyelidlessness You are right about the whyt - and I *really* meant that. (There is only a task posing as a question.)

Comment: @pst, and I maintain that it's a comment smell. The breadth of SO questions and answers is *so* broad that if there's a reason to ask "WHYT?" then there is almost certainly already a question and answer, at which point by all means flag it as a duplicate (and mark the relevant question and answer as the relevant duplicate). I also think it's relevant that the question (like so many) evolved in comments, and it's ripe for editing to clarify the intent of the question for posterity... but it's simply *not helpful* to respond dismissively, and "WHYT" (like "LMGTFY") is dismissive.

Comment: @pst, I'm not inclined to take this to chat because I think we're at the point of resolution the best we'll encounter it... but I appreciate this exchange, and want to make that known. I know that what I value about SO isn't the same as everyone else, and I appreciate that a perfectly innocent question could trigger meaningful discourse about why we're here and contributing. Thanks for sparring, even though I'm sure neither of us needs to spend time sparring in a comment section on a regex question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
/^\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}$/
```

refactoring, not to repeat:

```
/^(?:\d{1,3}(?:-|$)){6}/
```

The idea is the same as eyelidlessness's, but testing the presence of the `-` at the end of string

Edited to remove the matching end `-`:

```
/^(?:\d{1,3}(?:-(?!$)|$)){6}/
```

Had to added that *intuitive* negative lookahead. If I were you, I'd stick with the repetitive version - the future you will thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to refactor that regex so to do not repeat the `\d{1,3}` part?

Comment: @Tudor, that is an interesting way to remove repetition, but the lack of constraints at the start and end allow some discrepancies. For instance, `122-162-281-05-00-221-` would match. It would still match a partial of `a122-162-281-05-00-221-q`.

Comment: @eyelidlessness agree, but also, your regex matches `"-122-162-281-05-00-221"`

Comment: @Tudor, somehow I missed that!

Comment: @Tudor Constantin, the repetitive version (`\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}`) doesn't work for `-122-162-281-5-0-221`.

Comment: @Backo that's right, I fixed it

Comment: @Tudor, I find the repetitive code less intuitive than the refactored code (whether you put the constraints at the start, as I did, or at the end, as you did). When I encounter repetitive code, I'm **forced** to scan it for variations in the repetition. When I encounter code that is less repetitive, I'm able to know *intuitively* that there is no variation in each repetition. The point where this breaks down is where readability is harmed... and obviously, when dealing with regex (or other dense/complex syntax) that depends on the expertise of the reader of the syntax.

Comment: @eyelidlessness - I am a perl developer for several years and we do quite a lot of regexes - however, I'd rather encounter the full repetitive version than either yours, or mine, or Kenneth's shorter, optimized versions

Comment: @Tudor, I would personally *write* Kenneth's, but prefer to encounter either my own simplified version or yours, in order to quickly ascertain its purpose and correctness.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Tudor Constantin can be simplified:

```
/^(?!-)(?:(?:^|-)\d{1,3}){6}$/
```

Edited to remove further repetition.

Edited again to disallow a leading hyphen. This edit requires lookahead, which some engines do not support. It does, however, only use a fixed-width lookahead, which maximizes compatibility with engines that support lookahead.

To explain the latest pattern:

`^` specifies the beginning of a string (or line).

`(?!-)` utilizes lookahead to disallow matching a string whose first character is a hyphen.

`(?:(?:^|-)\d{1-3}){6}` specifies a repetition of a pattern that must either be the start of a string or a hyphen, followed by one to three digits, repeated six times.

`$` ensures the string (or line) ends after the prior repetition.

Comment: I like `(?:^|-)`. Especially the `^|-` part.

Comment: What is the difference with regex answered by @Tudor Constantin?

Comment: Figuring this out taught me something neat about regex. Because `^` was already enforced, the `-` could not occur at the start. It's probably not the most **efficient** expression, but it's *certainly* not more repetitive than necessary.

Comment: @Backo, my answer specifies a pattern that: has a set of six segments (specified by `{6}`), each of which either begins the string (`^`) or begins with a hyphen (`-`), followed by one to three digits. The difference is that there is no unnecessary repetition.

Comment: so, your code will match `-122-162-281-5-0-221`? and `122-162-281-5-0-221-`?

Comment: @Backo, no it won't. Your specification did not allow for those. Tudor's edit would allow the second and match a partial of the first.

Comment: I tried your regex at http://rubular.com/ and both `-122-162-281-5-0-221` and `122-162-281-5-0-221-` matches! I would like those are not matched (those are not valid during Ruby on Rails validation).

Comment: @Backo, `-122-162-281-0-221` does match. `122-162-281-5-0-221-` does not. I will work on a way to solve the first.

Comment: Sorry for the `122-162-281-5-0-221-` (it doesn't match), but the first still does.

Comment: @Backo: I updated the expression to disallow a leading hyphen.

Comment: When you say "simplified" I think "convoluted". In this case I would just repeat it 6 times. Now, if we're talking about 60 (or some arbitrary number) or had a more complex match ..

Comment: @pst, it depends on the purpose of the simplification. One may pursue such a simplification in order to learn how to write a more complex expression and keep it manageable. I think the *explicitness* of my expression speaks for itself, in a way that a longer set of repetitions might, at the expense of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

Not that there's anything technically wrong with a lookahead, but I think for intuitiveness I'd shorten Tudor Constantin's suggestion to:

```
/^\d{1,3}(?:-\d{1,3}){5}$/
```

Comment: Since the author asked (in comments) to limit repetition, it's worth noting that there was then an effort to remove repetition even where it would make sense to keep it. Your answer is definitely *simpler*.

Comment: @eyelidlessness Sure, but in this case I think it is warranted. Your expression is slick, but even I was initially thrown of by the repetition of `^` in your pattern (I do understand why you wrote it that way). Regex is hard enough to read for novices; refactoring just to save keystrokes is counter-productive (IMHO). For someone starting out, I would wholly suggest Tudor Constantin's approach as even what I propose above could be slightly awkward to read.

Comment: you'll note I didn't save any keystrokes (your pattern is shorter than mine), I addressed questions asked in the comments. The questioner expressly asked how to reduce repetition: that is what I (and Tudor) provided. You'll also note that I said to Tudor that yours is the expression I would write in the course of my work. (SO throttles edits, but it was also *identical* to my first submission, before I saw requests to reduce repetition.)

Comment: @eyelidlessness Honestly, it really is the double `^` that worries me more than the lookahead. Lookahead is difficult to explain to a novice, but explaining why you can use the `^` more than once in a string...that I think would end up being just as (if not more difficult) to explain than the lookahead. I'm basing this statement on the dealings I've had in other questions.

Comment: you'll also note I'm not arguing that yours isn't the better answer. **It's the one I would write if I had this requirement. I only wrote mine to satisfy comment requests to reduce repetition.**